# What's the contrary of picorage (cherry picking)?

Tags: antonyme, word-request

Cherry picking in artificial intelligence research (and in some other contexts) is the act of choosing examples of good predictions. I believe it is translated as *picorage* in French. I wonder which word or phrase expresses the contrary of "picorage" is (i.e., choosing examples of bad predictions).

Comment: Is the contrary to choose examples of bad predictions, or to not introduce any bias by randomly selecting predictions, good or bad?

Comment: What about "sélection/échantillon aléatoire uniforme" and "sélection/échantillon ciblé(e)"?

Comment: @Frank thanks, in that case I am trying to find a way to say that one intentionally select bad example. Sélection/échantillon ciblé(e) is pretty good but is missing the fact that the chosen examples are bad.

Comment: "Sélection d'exemples négatifs"? "Sélection de prédictions négatives"? if you have a threshold and want to expose those details, you could say something like "sélection de prédictions en dessous du seuil" maybe. Or maybe simply "sélection de prédictions manquées/incorrectes". Maybe that's the best: "sélection de prédictions incorrectes".

Comment: The opposite of cherry-picking is not "choosing examples of bad predictions", but rather something like "choosing a fair representation of results (here ai predictions) than doesn't misrepresent the quality of something (here a prediction tool)". You can cherry-pick only a few good examples to misrepresent something to be better than it is, but you can also cherry-pick bad examples to make something look worse than it is, if you want to dishonestly criticize it. It's also called cherry-picking. The opposite would just be fair representation, and I don't think it has a name.

Comment: Can you cite a source with the specific meaning of "cherry picking" you're talking about @FranckDernoncourt? As others have said, your definition of the term might be too narrow to start with, making it difficult to generalize it to something as broad as the "opposite of cherry-picking".

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't aware of that ***picorage*** usage.

I would say in both cases: ***tests volontairement/délibérément biaisés***.

I have also found:

- *échantillonnage non probabiliste*
- *[échantillonnage de commodité](https://explorable.com/fr/echantillonnage-de-commodite)*

Comment: "échantillonnage de commodité" sounds neat. I can hear the French sarcasm in it.

Comment: I would add "échantillon non représentatif".

Comment: @Graffito Oui, *non représentatif* est plus courant que *non probabiliste* mais comme ce dernier, n'exclut pas l'erreur "de bonne foi". Peut être, *échantillonnage volontairement non représentatif*.

Comment: J'ai ajouté à ma réponse _échantillon probabiliste uniforme_.

Comment: @Frank Un *échantillon probabiliste uniforme* n'est pas spécialement biaisé, si ?

Comment: @jlliagre Non, je le donne comme exemple d'un "contraire" de "cherry picking": "uniforme" devrait évoquer la "distribution uniforme" en statistique, qui ne comporte aucun biais.

Comment: @Frank J'ai du mal à comprendre dans ta réponse que le quatrième élément de ta liste est à prendre différemment des trois autres. Tu devrais élaborer un petit peu.

Comment: Petite variante : "tests/échantillons *délibérément* biaisés".

Comment: @jlliagre Bonne suggestion - j'ai retravaillé un peu ma réponse - c'est mieux?

Comment: @Graffito Je l'ajoute, merci !

Comment: @jlliagre _de commodité_ me semble un peu bizarre ou au moins vague ici?

Comment: @Frank Le terme fait partie du jargon de certains statisticiens mais me semble quand même assez clair. Les échantillons retenus sont les plus "commodes" à choisir. L'expression traduit l'anglais *convenience sampling*. Ça ne va pas aussi loin que le *cherry picking* mais on s'en approche.

Comment: @jlliagre Mais l'OP cherche le _contraire_ de _cherry picking_, non? J'ai l'impression que _de commodité_ est juste une autre façon de biaiser l'échantillon - le biais est simplement maintenant: "ce qui est le plus facile à échantillonner", mais c'est un bel et bien un biais?

Comment: @Frank Le contraire du *cherry picking*, c'est aussi du *cherry picking* ! On ne choisit simplement pas les même cerises ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, l'ambiguïté que je souligne pour le mot _contraire_ dans cette question.

Answer (score 2):

In the specific context of artificial intelligence research in France (probably others too, but I can speak for this one), people usually simply use the English expression "cherry picking" in the wide meaning of "to purposefully bias the way you choose your data so it says what you want it to say", whether it is positive or negative.

It would both cover purposefully ignoring the data that makes your model look bad and choosing specific rare datapoints for which the state-of-the-art doesn't work as well as your model: as soon as you are dishonest about how you pick your data, that's cherry-picking, the fact you choose positive or negative examples isn't relevant.

I have heard adventurous people use a direct translation "cueillir  des cerises" for "to cherry-pick", but I wouldn't say it is idiomatic. Most would simply say "faire du cherry-picking".

Comment: Suivant le but, on peut vouloir montrer des exemples négatifs sans nécessairement être biaisé. Par exemple, on peut choisir X exemples positifs, X exemples négatifs et montrer les deux échantillons. Je suis d'accord que "cherry picking" évoque le biais.

Comment: @Frank Tout à fait. On peut même exhiber un unique cas très atypique qui "donne raison" à un modèle sans que ce soit du cherrypicking, là où ça en devient c'est quand on présente (explicitement ou implicitement) cet échantillon comme représentatif alors qu'on sait qu'il ne l'est pas.

Answer (score 1):

There is a little bit of ambiguity as to what the opposite of "cherry picking good examples" should be. It could be to "cherry pick bad examples", or it could be to "not cherry pick", ie to do an *unbiased* selection of predictions.

If you want to say that the samples are *biased* ("cherry picking bad examples") towards bad predictions, I think you could go with something like:

> Sélection de prédictions incorrectes

> Échantillon de prédictions incorrectes

> Exemples de prédictions incorrectes

If you want to say that an *unbiased* sample was chosen (in particular without any bias towards good or bad predictions, no "cherry picking"), I think the following would work, since the [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution) in statistics is the one that will not "cherry pick" any sample in particular:

> Échantillon aléatoire uniforme